# PLS-00201 - identifier 'Stored-Procedure-Name' must be declared

Tags: function, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using oracledb package in Nodejs to run a stored procedure in Oracle that returns a referance cursor but I get the error PLS-00201 - identifier 'GETDATA' must be declared, the stored procedure is defined in a package on my Oracle database called MYPACKAGE. So far I have tried running grant execute on MYPACKAGE to usernameValue in sql developer but didn't help. Below is my code:

I'd really appreciate your help!

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb'); 

var numRows = 2; 

exports.test = function(req, res) {
oracledb.getConnection({  
     user: "usernameValue",  
     password: "passwordValue",  
     connectString: "ServerName/Service_Name"  
}, function(err, connection) {  
     if (err) {  
          console.error("in connection error "+err.message);  
          return;  
     }
     var bindvars = {
      inSchemaOwner:  'MySchema',  
      cRefCur:  { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir : oracledb.BIND_OUT }
    };
    connection.execute(
      "BEGIN GETDATA(:inSchemaOwner, :cRefCur); END;",
      bindvars,
      function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        console.log(result.outBinds.cRefCur.metaData);
        fetchRowsFromRS(connection, result.outBinds.cRefCur, numRows);
      });
});  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the stored procedure `GETDATA` is in the package `MYPACKAGE`, then to call it, you need to prefix the stored procedure with the package name:

```
      "BEGIN MYPACKAGE.GETDATA(:inSchemaOwner, :cRefCur); END;",
```

Otherwise, Oracle thinks you are trying to call a ['standalone' procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373) named `GETDATA`.  'Standalone' stored procedures exist outside of a package.

Additionally, if the package `MYPACKAGE` is in a schema other than `usernameValue`, you need to prefix the procedure name with the package owner as well, for example:

```
      "BEGIN PACKAGEOWNER.MYPACKAGE.GETDATA(:inSchemaOwner, :cRefCur); END;",
```

Finally, in order to call the stored procedure, the procedure needs to be declared in the package specification as well as defined in the package body.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked! I didn't put the package name before it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure** you have added the if using other user then **username, package and the procedure name**. Otherwise it will not be possible to identify the extract procedure.